# Encrypt traffic between my onion site and exit relays

Tags: onion-services, security, exit-relays, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt all traffic between the last relay and my hidden service site? (I have tried to use an ssl certificate and configure tor like that: `HiddenServicePort 443 127.0.0.1:443` but it don't work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're running a hidden service all connections from a Tor client to it are encrypted end-to-end

Comment: https://www.torproject.org/images/htw2.png (the last link between exit node and hidden service is unencrypted)

Comment: That's regular Tor.
https://www.torproject.org/images/THS-6.png

Comment: @yohann2008 tor to regular internet connections are unencrypted from the exit point. but tor to tor connections are encrypted end to end

Comment: This is confusing, because the protocol shown in the address bar is http. Are you saying that .onion addresses used through tor are using a layer on *top* of http to encrypt requests?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated you may offer your service as a hidden service in addition to the public one. That way connections using the onion address will always be encrypted.

The Tor website has [a manual](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) for configuring a hidden service.